# Angularfire2 Refresh token after expiration

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 for Authentication.  when token expiry , i need to get new valid token . current code

```
private user: Observable<any>;
constructor(pprivate _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
}

refreshToken() {
  this.user.switchMap(
      (user) => {
          user.getIdToken(true).then((tk) => {
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', tk);;
          });
      }
  );
}
```

Is this correct way to refresh token ?

Comment: Not sure how firebase auth. works, but normally, upon authentication, you should get a refresh token together with access token. When access token expires, you send refresh token to obtain a new access token. Therefore, send a refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

`getIdToken` will refresh the ID token when it expires or return the cached ID token if it is not expired. Ideally that should be enough. You would have a mechanism to get a valid token anytime you need it.

If you need to proactively refresh the token before expiration, you can do something like you suggested, but you need to keep track of the expiration of the ID token. It is quite inefficient to do that on each call.
The ID token lifetime is 1 hour. You can force refresh a couple of minutes before expiration. One way to get the expiration time, is by parsing the `exp` field from the token payload.

Comment: This answer is great but can you please add code examples

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that what is the main idea that you used another token to manipulate your auth. I realize that the AngularFireAuth has its own way to manage token and other parts. The thing is, because you declared a variable "user" as an Observable, so every time you use it, it supposes be embed with "async". I can give you an example which works as well in my application:

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="user | async">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="onLogout()"> Logout </a>
    </li>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!(user | async)">
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/auth/login"> Login </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/auth/register"> Register </a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```